# GPL Ghostscript 8.70: Can't start ijs server

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, printer-control-language

I'm trying to get ghostscript to convert PDFs to PCL-5 (or 5e) using a driver capable of being configured (the built-in drivers produce very surprisingly large output, and I need something capable of being tweaked).

I have gutenprint compiled, and have placed the ijsgutenprint executable at `/home/marcintustin/webapps/django/oneclickcosvirt/bin/ijsgutenprint.5.2`. When I try to invoke it with ghostscript with

```
gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOCIE -dSAFER -sDEVICE=ijs \ 
-sIjsServer=/home/marcintustin/webapps/django/oneclickcosvirt/bin/ijsgutenprint.5.2  \
-sDeviceManufacturer=vendor  -sDeviceModel=name -sOutputFile=- - < sztst.pdf  > sztst.pcl
```

I get the error `GPL Ghostscript 8.70: Can't start ijs server "/home/marcintustin/webapps/django/oneclickcosvirt/bin/ijsgutenprint.5.2"`. I am mystified because the file is at the given location, is set executable, and can be invoked without error from the commandline. Any ideas on what's wrong / another way to solve this?

(I'm doing this on a shared host, to which I am not root, so I can't configure system-wide printing, and I'd prefer not to install any printing-related daemons unless absolutely necessary).

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that gutenprint, in addition to the `ijsgutenprint.5.2` binary, needs to have *in the same directory where the binary is installed* a directory called `.libs` containing further files. (The `.objects` directory also generated during build is not required in the installation).

Take note if performing a manual install!